# Can we get user information using Gigya Token

Tags: gigya

Whenever resetting the password, i will get a link including password reset token using this token **how can i get the user related information**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible.
The reset password token can only be used to reset the password via call to [accounts.resetPassword API](http://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/accounts.resetPassword+REST) (parameter name: passwordResetToken).

In order to get user related information the [accounts.getAccountInfo API](http://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/accounts.getAccountInfo+REST) should be called, which require other parameters.

HTH

Comment: This is correct. Gigya does not provide a way to retrieve information about the user from a password reset token because it would dangerously expose user information to do so.  If there were a way to do this, then it would open up the possibility of hacker exploiting the information both directly through the exposure of a Login Identifier and indirectly through the use a user's email address to social engineer a compromise of a user's account.